# How to get the value update in a list in Firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a list of string in Firestore and if i add a new item to the List or update a String item in the List..

i want to get the value, if i add or if i update the List. The string i want to get the `before value` of the String and `after value updated String` in the list i updated ...

[image: inage]

in my code i keep getting all the data of the "interest" instead of the value add or if update the before string and after string

here is my code

```
exports.dashboadNewsPost = functions.firestore.document("universities/universities").onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    console.log("No Device");
  }
  //before value insert if update a String in the interest List
  const beforeValueAdded = snapshot.before.data()["interest"]
  //after value insert if update a String in the interest List
  const afterValueAdded = snapshot.after.data()["interest"]
  console.log(`this is  before ${beforeValueAdded}`);
  console.log(`this is  after ${afterValueAdded}`);
});
```

here is the  output of the console is.
Before:: look at the first index which is University Of Alba Iulia

[image: before]

here after::  University Of Alba Iulia have been updated to University Of Alba Iulia1...

what i want is, i only what to get before update value and after update value

[image: after]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. The value you get from the document will always be the full `interest` array. If you want to determine what item was added/updated/removed, you will have to check for that yourself in the code. --- If that does not answer your question, please edit it to show the output you get from the `console.log` statements and what about that output is not what you expected.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay let me explain like this : const a= ["a", "ab"], so if i update the value of ab to "abc".... i want to get the value of before which is AB and after as ABC.... i think with this i can perform any other stuff, if this is done...

Comment: Instead of clarifying in the comments, can you edit your question to do so? Aside from that: the use-case was clear, but I don't understand what your question for us is. Can you show the output of the `console.log` statements and indicate in there what isn't working?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated with the output.. i only change the first index which is the "University Of Alba Iulia" to 
"University Of Alba Iulia1" . So i only want to get this two value only irrespective of the index but now is getting me all the array...

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#specifying_the_document_path:%7E:text=Functions%20only%20respond%20to%20document%20changes%2C%20and%20cannot%20monitor%20specific%20fields%20or%20collections):

> Functions only respond to document changes, and cannot monitor specific **fields** or collections

However, you can create a custom function where you'll compare the old and new value of your array by using an index. See sample code below:

```
exports.dashboadNewsPost = functions.firestore.document("universities/universities").onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  if (!change.exists) {
    console.log("No Device");
  }

  const newValue = snapshot.after.data()||{};
  const previousValue = snapshot.before.data()||{};

  const newInterest = newValue.interest;
  const oldInterest = previousValue.interest;

  for (let index = 0; index < newInterest.length; index++) {
    if (oldInterest[index] !== newInterest[index]) {
      console.log(oldInterest[index], " => ", newInterest[index]);
    }
  }
});
```